# How can I (or any user) pull comment discussions into Meta?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta

Occasionally, some [question comments become long discussions](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/box-to-store-non-files-in-filing-cabinet-drawer) about some detail(s) that make answers unacceptable for one or more seemingly shallow reasons.

What is the best way to short-circuit these?

- Continue to engage them then and there at the bottom of the Question/Comment thread
- Pull/Push them into Meta somehow
- Any other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard action for (excessive) discussion in comments is to move them to a separate chatroom. The option for this [sometimes appears automatically to involved users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371688/295232); ♦ moderators are [always able to move comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93444/295232). From my experience (as a regular user) this doesn't happen too often on Lifehacks.SE, but when it does, you're welcome to flag the post for moderator attention.

Moving the discussion to Meta is an option if it has the potential to become a more general community discussion whether certain types of answers (and questions) are acceptable or not.